# What is the difference in these two closures?

Tags: javascript, closures, iife

I have recently learnt there is a few ways to create a closure (not just returning a function from a function), but also referencing the function as a callback in an event listener. This creates a closure too which explains why you can call an innerFunction using an eventListener even after an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) has finished executing and has not returned anything.

I like to think the main power of a closure is that not only does it find a variable in an outer function to use in an inner function, but it also updates its value so it can be stored. For example, you can push into an array and update it inside an outer function or update a score set as a primitive on an outer function.

However, if you can create a closure via referencing a function via an event Listener then why can you not update a local variable every time a function is called via an event listener, see below for what I am trying to get at.

```
function increaseScore(){
   var score = 0;
   score ++;
   console.log(score); // console.logs one everytime the event occurs
                       // despite the event listener creating a
                       // closure for this funciton
}
document.addEventListener("click", increaseScore);

function addScore(){
  var score = 0;

  return function (){ // This too is a closure created in a different way
                      // and increases every time the event is called
   score ++;
   console.log(score); // 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. every time the event occurs
  }
}
var keepScore = addScore();
document.addEventListener("click", keepScore);
```

Why is this the case? They are both examples of closures, one via an event Listener, another via returning a function, but only the function that returns a function gets updated from its original value of zero and is held in memory for every time the function is called and the first function resets to zero every time, and therefore is only ever printing 1 to the console. I can’t find an explanation anywhere.

Comment: @Bergi is there anyway you can help with this as you gave me a pro answer before and it leads directly on from this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that because the global variable is in the outer environment and a closure only exists if it closes over variables not within its funciton but within its scope ? If so if a function is an inner funciton does it close over everything in its outer function and then everything in the global environment ? Thanks

Comment: `var score = 0; score++;` can be replaced by `var score = 1;`. In a function scope of a script in strict mode, as well as anywhere in modules, there’s no observable difference between the two, as far as I know. Your `var score` is in function scope, so script vs. module makes no difference, and the one exception I can think of where strict vs. non-strict matters is if you were using a `with` statement, which you’re not. Therefore these are equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is not a closure, since `var score` is declared *within* the function. Once you move that line outside of the function, it will work as expected (and the function will close over the global variable):

```
var score = 0;
function increaseScore(){
  score ++;
  console.log(score);
}
document.addEventListener("click", increaseScore);
```

---

Better examples of how to create closures without `return`ing them might be

```
var keepScore;
function addScore(){
  var score = 0;

  keepScore = function (){ // this too is a closure
    score++;
    console.log(score);
  };
}
addScore();
document.addEventListener("click", keepScore);
```

```
function addScore(){
  var score = 0;

  function keepScore(){ // this too is a closure
    score++;
    console.log(score);
  };
  document.addEventListener("click", keepScore);
}
addScore();
```